# How to conditionally subtract numbers based on a value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Table1:                               Table3:
Balance | Transfer                    Balance 
20,000    Yes
30,000    Partial 
40,000    Partial
50,000    Yes

Table2: 
Balance | Transfer 
10,000    Yes
20,000    Partial 
30,000    Yes
21,000    Partial
```

I have 2 tables containing balance amount and a column with a dropdown list (Yes, No, Partial). I need that everything that is selected as partial in Table1 and Table 2, to be subtracted.

So in the example below, I will need to subtract 30,000 from Table1 - 20,000 from Table2. And for the other partial balance as well. Every case will be different so I may end up having 4 or 5 partials (always will be the same amount of partials in each table) in different cells. I am stuck in writing a VBA code where I can say that everything that says partial in table 1 will subtract what is marked as partial in table 2 and then move the remaining amount to table3. This is only one small process of my whole macro so I need to have it in VBA. My ideal output should be:

```
Table3: 
Balance
10,000 - Partial1
19,000 - Partial2
```

Current code looks like this:

```
If Sheets ("1").Cells(1,10).Value = "Yes" Then 'Rows that are marked as yes
Sheets('1").Cells(1,4).Copy 'This will copy data from that specific row
Sheets("2").Range("A28").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats 'Paste value in other sheet and table

ElseIf Sheets("1").Cells(i, 10).Value = "Partial" And Sheets("1").Cells(i, 10).Value = "Partial" Then 
'Here is where I need to specify to grab the balance from Table1 and subtract it to value in Table2 that says Partial and paste the result in Sheets("2")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Does this need to be Row-Based, or full entry? (e.g., will Table3 have 1 record for 29000, or 2 records for 10000 and 19000?)  Are you familiar with the `INDEX`, `FILTER,` SUMIF` and/or `AGGREGATE` functions?

Comment: Seems like you could do this with a formula pretty quickly - no VBA required.  Also would hel pto show the expected output in table 34

Comment: @TimWilliams This is just a small part of the whole vba I currently have. So I will need to add this porton. This is just a example, but there can be million cases with 10 rows, different numbers, etc, so basically I need to trigger that where it says "Partial" then subtract those 2 balances and show me the result in other table.

Comment: @Chronocidal Table 3 will have 2 records, 10,000 and 19,000 in different rows. I am familiar with those functions but not sure how to specify: If Table1 - Row 2 - Partial and Table2 - Row3 - Partial, then grab balances of both, subtract, and show me result in table3.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare the first "Partial" from Table1 with the second "Partial" from Table2, et cetera.  Technically, you can do this without VBA, using `INDEX` and `FILTER` (Office365) or `AGGREGATE` (Earlier versions of Office): (I will treat `Table1` and `Table2` as Named Ranges for simplicity)

(You *may* want to include a `TRIM` when you are running the comparison, in case your "Partial" has leading or trailing spaces)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(Table1, TRIM(Index(Table1,,2))="Partial"), Row()-1, 1), 0) - IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(Table2, TRIM(Index(Table2,,2))="Partial"), Row()-1, 1), 0)

=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1, AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(Index(Table1,,2))/(TRIM(Index(Table1,,2))="Partial"), Row()-1), 1), 0) - IFERROR(INDEX(Table2, AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(Index(Table2,,2))/(TRIM(Index(Table2,,2))="Partial"), Row()-1), 1), 0)
```

This means you can use VBA to apply the formula, and then flatten it to just the values.  *Here*, I will be treating `Table1`, `Table2`, and `Table3` as `Range` arguments (including Headers) for the Sub - again, for simplicity.

```
Sub PartialTableDifferences(Table1 AS Range, Table2 AS Range, Table3 As Range)
    Dim Partials_Table1 AS Long, Partials_Table2 AS Long, RangeToFill AS Range

    Partials_Table1 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Table1.Columns(2),"Partial")
    Partials_Table2 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Table2.Columns(2),"Partial")

    If Partials_Table1 + Partials_Table2 < 1 Then Exit Sub 'No Partials to compare

    'Set the correct size for Table 3
    If Partials_Table1 > Partials_Table2 Then
        Set RangeToFill = Table3.Offset(1,0).Resize(Partials_Table1,1)
    Else
        Set RangeToFill = Table3.Offset(1,0).Resize(Partials_Table2,1)
    End If

    With RangeToFill
        'Office365
        '.Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(" & Table1.Columns(1).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ", TRIM(" & Table1.Columns(2).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ")=""Partial""), Row()-" & Table3.Cells(1,1).Row & "), 0) " & _
            "- IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(" & Table2.Columns(1).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ", TRIM(" & Table2.Columns(2).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ")=""Partial""), Row()-" & Table3.Cells(1,1).Row & "), 0)"

        'Older Versions
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(" & Table1.Columns(1).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ", AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(" & Table1.Columns(2).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ")/(TRIM(" & Table1.Columns(2).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ")=""Partial""), Row()-" & Table3.Cells(1,1).Row & ")), 0) " & _
            "- IFERROR(INDEX(" & Table2.Columns(1).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ", AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(" & Table2.Columns(2).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ")/(TRIM(" & Table2.Columns(2).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ")=""Partial""), Row()-" & Table3.Cells(1,1).Row & ")), 0)"

        .Calculate
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Procedure1()

'1.declare variables
'2.clear old search results
'3.find records that match criteria and paste them

Dim transfer As String
Dim i As Integer 'row counter


Sheets("2").Range("A12:D28").ClearContents 'Where I want to transfer the data


For i = 12 To 28

If Sheets("1").Cells(i, 10).Value = "Yes" Then 'Where current data is located

Sheets("1").Cells(i, 4).Copy 'Additional data I want to move

Sheets("2").Range("A28").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Sheets("1").Cells(i, 9).Copy 'Additional data I want to move

Sheets("2").Range("B28").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Sheets("1").Cells(i, 1).Copy 'Additional data I want to move

Sheets("2").Range("C28").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Sheets("FSR Analysis").Cells(i, 5).Copy 'This is the balance

Sheets("Transfer Form").Range("D28").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

'This code is fine, I need help with the one below'

End If
        
Next i


End Sub

Sub Procedure2()

Dim i As Integer 'row counter

For i = 12 To 28

If Sheets("1").Cells(i, 10).Value = "Partial" Then

Sheets("1").Cells(i, 4).Copy 'Additional data I want to move

Sheets("2").Range("A28").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Sheets("1").Cells(i, 9).Copy 'Additional data I want to move

Sheets("2").Range("B28").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Sheets("1").Cells(i, 1).Copy 'Additional data I want to move

Sheets("2").Range("C28").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Sheets("1").Cells(i, 5).Copy 'This is the balance column from Table1 that I am trying to subtract. I need first to specify the tables as ranges (not sure how) and then specify that for those wthat says PArtial in table1 and table2 subtract and move to sheets"2"

Sheets("2").Range("D28").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats


End If
        
Next i


End Sub
```